# getData("worldclim", download=FALSE,...) from a local file bio_2-5m_bil.zip

Tags: r, zip

In R, I intended to download data using this:

```
worldclim <- getData("worldclim", var = "bio", res = 2.5)
```

But it failed repeatedly. The error massage reads:

```
Error in utils::download.file(url = aurl, destfile = fn, quiet = FALSE,  : 
  download from 'https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/climate/worldclim/1_4/grid/cur/bio_2-5m_bil.zip' failed
```

I instead downloaded bio_2-5m_bil.zip. I have not been successful in extracting data from this zip folder. I suppose I should use "download = FALSE" as an option, but how can I specify the rest so that I would be able to extract the data the same as the one I would get from:

```
worldclim <- getData("worldclim", var = "bio", res = 2.5)
```

? Thank you very much for your help.